# static and non-static difference in Kth Smallest Element in a BST

Tags: java, static, non-static

In this problem, if I make the `count` variable in the second line `static`, as shown, the `kthSmallest()` method computes the wrong answer. If the variable is instead made non-`static` then the correct answer is computed. Non-static methods can use static variables, so why is there a difference?

```
class Solution {
    public static int count = 0;
    public int res = 0;

    public int kthSmallest(TreeNode root, int k) {
        inorder(root,k);
        return res;
    }

    public void inorder(TreeNode root, int k) {
        if (root == null) return;
        inorder(root.left,k);
        count++;
        if (count == k) {
            res = root.val;
            return;
        }
        inorder(root.right,k);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you understand what `static` means and how recursion works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see no reason why the result of *a single run* of your `kthSmallest()` method would be affected by whether `count` is `static`, but if you perform *multiple* runs, whether sequentially or in parallel, you will certainly have a problem.  `count` being `static` means every instance of class `Solution` shares that variable, which you initialize once to zero, and then only increment.  A second run of the method, whether on the same or a different instance of `Solution`, will continue with the value of `count` left by the previous run.

Making `count` non-`static` partially addresses that issue, by ensuring that every instance of `Solution` has its own `count` variable.  You still have a problem with performing multiple `kthSmallest()` computations using the same instance, but you can perform one correct run per instance.  If you're testing this via some automated judge then it's plausible that it indeed does create a separate instance for each test case.

But even that is not a *complete* solution.  You still get at most one run per instance, and you're not even sure to get that if an attempt is made to perform two concurrent runs using the same instance.  The fundamental problem here is that you are using instance (or class) variables to hold state specific to a single run of the `kthSmallest()` method.

You ought instead to use local variables of that method, communicated to other methods, if needed, via method arguments and / or return values.  For example:

```
class Solution {
    // no class or instance variables at all

    public int kthSmallest(TreeNode root, int k) {
        // int[1] is the simplest mutable container for an int
        int[] result = new int[1];
        inorder(root, k, result);
        return result[0]; 
    }

    // does not need to be public:
    // returns the number of nodes traversed (not necessarily the whole subtree)
    int inorder(TreeNode root, int k, int[] result) {
        if (root == null) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            // nodes traversed in the subtree, plus one for the present node
            int count = inorder(root.left, k, result) + 1;

            if (count == k) {
                result[0] = root.val;
            } else {
                count += inorder(root.right, k, result);
            }

            return count;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Very clear John, `count += inorder(root.right, k, result);` should be `count += inorder(root.right, k-count, result);`,  thanks for your answering and code formatting!